# What happens when two photon of same polarization enters in the polarizing beam-splitter(PBS)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

It is well established that if two photons of the same polarization, identical wavelength, phase, and spatial distribution of wavefunction enter a non-polarizing beam splitter (N-PBS), they exhibit the Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) effect. Essentially, they show bunching behavior. But what exactly happens for the same setup if we use a polarizing beam splitter (PBS)? Photons interact in the PBS. Do they bunch or not? Please provide a detailed mathematical description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is totally fine.